# Conferindo um radioButton

Tags: c#

Bom dia ! 
criei um pequeno sistema que utiliza alguns componentes radioButton, 
porém quando não marco nenhum o sistema gera um erro, alguem sabe 
como posso fazer uma conferencia se algum radioButton foi marcado. 
Segue abaixo o codigo:

```
RadioButton rbnTurno = groupBox2.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().SingleOrDefault(r => r.Checked);
RadioButton rbnCategoria = groupBox1.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().SingleOrDefault(r => r.Checked);
RealizarProcessamento(rbnTurno, rbnCategoria, Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text), Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text));
```

Comment: Qual o erro exatamente que gera? Melhor se for o stacktrace todo.

Comment: Provavelmente você deve estar executando e a variável `rbnTurno` deve estar nula, porque não tem nenhum radio selecionado, dai quando você passa para o método `RealizarProcessamento` dá erro. Você tem que tratar isso, e até exibir uma mensagem se for o caso.

Comment: Olá ! Consegui resolver, e foi só tratar para conferir se existe algum radiobutton selecionado, ai deu certo. obrigado...

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar uma expressão lambda pra isso.

Veja o exemplo abaixo. Vale ressaltar que se você estiver utilizando os RadioButtons dentro de um container, será necessário informar conforme faço abaixo no groupBox1.

```
 var listaDeRadioButtons = groupBox1.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().Any(x=>x.Checked);

   if (!listaDeRadioButtons)
       MessageBox.Show("Selecione um Radio Button", "Atenção", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado.